# UART is not working with start up application in Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, uart, nxp-microcontroller

I'm new to Linux world. But really interesting to learn new things. I'm having an issue while working on UART with Start-up application. I have made a service that talk to nRF chip through UART. It seem working pretty good when I start that service manually by ./service_name on the terminal after booting up both nRF and NXP imx8mm. But when I start service as a start up application with deamon. It seem UART receive is not working properly.

Here is my UART configuration.

```
static int nordic_init(void) 
{
    int ret = UART_ERR_DEFAULT;

    fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: uart device open = %i\n", fd);
        ret = UART_ERR_FILE;
        goto error;
    }
    /*baudrate 115200, 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop bit */
    set_interface_attribs(fd, B115200);

    isUARTInit = 1;
    return UART_ERR_NONE;

error:
    return ret;
}

static int set_interface_attribs(int fd, int speed) 
{
    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) < 0) {
        printf("Error from tcgetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, (speed_t)speed);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    /* ignore modem controls */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;         /* 8-bit characters */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;     /* no parity bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;     /* only need 1 stop bit */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;    /* no hardware flowcontrol */

    //     setup for non-canonical mode
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;


    //     fetch bytes as they become available
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;

    cfmakeraw(&tty);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        printf("Error from tcsetattr: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

    nordic_Tx(tx_data, 6);          //Send to Nordic nRF52840
    length = read(fd, rx_data, 4);  // read response of nRF52840
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Received data from nRF = %s", rx_data);
    printf("Received data from nRF = %s", rx_data);
    fflush(stdout);
```

I'm making my start-up application through the following way.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service Name Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/service_name

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

systemctl enable $SERVICE_NAME
```

[enter link description here](https://github.com/has58/nordic)
Please, let me know If I need to give you guys something else too

Thank you

Comment: "It seem UART receive is not working properly" is not a very concise problem statement. What exactly does it mean? Does the service run and then fail to receive? Any log entries or error codes?

Comment: Service is still running. It just receive wrong information on the UART receiving buffer
root@imx8mmevk:~# systemctl status nordic 
● nordic.service - nordic Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nordic.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-06-03 16:24:57 UTC; 59min ago
 Main PID: 384 (nordic)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 520.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/nordic.service
           └─384 /usr/sbin/nordic
Jun 03 16:32:40 imx8mmevk nordic[384]: Transfer  = >W0001
Jun 03 16:32:49 imx8mmevk nordic[384]: Received from nRF = s

Comment: [Edit] your post and include all of the relevant there.

Comment: Perhaps the settings have been clobbered by some other service such as "serial-getty". You can check the current settings using `sudo stty -aF /dev/YOURTTYDEVICENAME` and check how well they match the device settings done by your service. Does it work properly if you restart the service after booting up?

Comment: Yes, if I kill it and rerun it thought ./nordic it work. And setting are same in both cases. Here is my setting. I have break them into tow parts. speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0; 
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;

Comment: -parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

Comment: The only setting in the stty output that seems to be different to the things your code has changed is `time = 0` which is different to your `tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;`. However, that should not matter because the interbyte timer value in `time` is irrelevant when `min = 1`.

Comment: @IanAbbott *"However, that should not matter because the interbyte timer value in stime is irrelevant when min = 1"* -- That explanation is incorrect, and the termios  **man** page states explains it.  But in this case both VTIME and VMIN are irrelevant because the serial terminal is used in ***non-blocking*** mode.

Comment: @Haider *"It just receive wrong information on the UART receiving buffer"* -- You have provided no evidence to support that conclusion.  Your read code (which you neglect to post) is fetching bytes from a system buffer, which is several buffer copies removed from what the UART receives.

Comment: @sawdust The man page explains that when `c_cc[VMIN]` > 0, the interbyte timeout in `c_cc[VTIME]` does not start until *after* the first byte is received. But receiving a single byte satisfies the `read` return condition when `c_cc[VMIN]` is 1. That is why I wrote that the interbyte timeout is irrelevant when `min = 1`.

Comment: @sawdust I have included the part where I am reading the UART in the main post. And on my first comment as I mention it is printing receive data "s" instead of "<w".

Comment: Does replacting `TCSANOW` with `TCSAFLUSH` make any difference?

Comment: @IanAbbott - Thanks for pointing out the corner case.

Comment: @Haider -- Looks like you've appended five lines of code, but there's no context: it's not part of any procedure.  Show the actual code.  From what you have posted, I already see two, maybe three, problems.  Are these actually bugs?  I can't tell from just five naked lines out of context.  BTW your program is not *"reading from the UART"*.  What device node is the program opening?  It's probably a ***serial terminal***.

Comment: *"And on my first comment as I mention it is printing receive data "s" instead of "<w"."* -- Your first comment is unreadable because it has no line breaks.  Add the information to your post as suggested by @jwdonahue.

Comment: @sawdust I have a link that have a complete file. Please, have a glance at it.

Answer (score 1):

> UART is not working ...
> I'm having an issue while working on UART ...
> I have made a service that talk to nRF chip through UART. ...
> It seem UART receive is not working properly ...
> Here is my UART configuration ...

You consistently (and exclusively) refer to using the *"UART"*.
However your program accesses the device node **/dev/ttymxc2**, which is a *serial terminal*.
Linux userspace programs do not (normally) have access to hardware devices such as a UART, but do have access to the processing layer for terminals, aka ***termios***.
See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/%7Erubini/docs/serial/serial.html), especially Figure 3 depicting data flow, layers, and function calls when reading and writing.

---

Seems like your program has several issues that combine to give you the illusion that data "reception" is "not working" (correctly).
But the actual problem is that your program does not properly read from the serial terminal buffers, nor does your program accurately report what was (or was not) retrieved.
The net result is that your program can (incorrectly) report that it is "reading" data that seems meaningless.

```
    fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC | O_NONBLOCK);
```

The problems start with the specification of the O_NONBLOCK option when opening the serial terminal.  This results in non-blocking reads and writes, and is inefficient unless properly programmed.

```
            length = read(fd, rx_data, 4);  // read response of nRF52840
```

The next problem is the omission of testing the return code from the **read()** syscall.
Note also that despite the specification of `4` in the **read()** request, there is no guarantee that 4, 3, 2, or even 1 byte will be returned.

Since this is a non-blocking request, **read()** will not wait for any data to be available, and could return `0` (indicating no data) or `-1` with an ***errno*** of EAGAIN.
Despite the possibility of no valid data in the buffer, your code unconditionally assumes that there is data from the *"nRF chip"*.

```
            syslog(LOG_INFO, "Received data from nRF = %s", rx_data);
            printf("Received data from nRF = %s", rx_data);
```

Besides unconditionally assuming that there is (new, valid) data, the next problem is that the data is treated as a string.
But **read()** merely copies bytes into your buffer, and does not terminate the copy with a null byte.

So the iMX8 could receive nothing from the *"nRF chip"*, and then your program would use garbage values in place of what was "received".
Why you think the program "works" when started from the shell is unexplainable.

---

> It seem working pretty good when I start that service manually by ./service_name on the terminal after booting up both nRF and NXP imx8mm. But when I start service as a start up application with deamon. [sic] It seem UART receive is not working properly.

A salient difference between executing a program as a service versus from the shell is the definition of stdin, stdout and stderr (e.g. where does **printf()** output go?).

You have provided no indication that stdout has been redirected when your program is used as a service, so **printf()** output should end up in the syslog.
Yet you have provided just a few messages from the syslog or systemctl.
And those two messages to not correlate with the source code you have provided (e.g. `Transfer = ...` in syslog versus `Transfer Data value = ...` in source).

Have you even been checking the syslog for any error messages?
Have you added informational output to your program so that you can confirm that you're seeing all stdout messages?
Or are you expecting to see **printf()** output from the service on your system console just like (all other) shell output?

Comment: it helps me a lot to understand Linux more closely. I have add all the examination and below in answer section. Do you have a suggestion how should I write this service if not like this. Would it be a good idea to read and write on the different threads with blocking? Or is there a way I can send multiple commands without non-block. I'm open for any suggestion.
Thank you @sawdust

Comment: Your explanation for using non-blocking I/O makes no sense.  Your program is single-threaded, and the serial terminal is a single data channel.  There is absolutely nothing in that program that even tries to efficiently utilize the CPU.  The one **write()** explicitly waits for output, and two other **read()** s incessantly & inefficiently query the termios buffer for data.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sawdust for this detailed explanation. I'm new to Linux and trying to learn new things. I apologies for my wrong reference.

1. I used known non-blocking so I can write multiple commands on the serial terminal at the same time and able to read asynchronously.
2. It is working through shell because Nordic service print the statements on the console and those prints are correct and communication between nRF and iMX8 is also complete properly every time.
3. For the **printf()** output redirect. I have looked at syslog and all other log files it's not there. These are only available when I use **systemctl status nordic**.
4. I send few messages from **systemctl** because once communication break NXP will stop sending other commands. nordic service required ack **"<w"** from nRF to sent next command.

I apologies but I changes Transfer Data vlaue = ... to Transfer = while writing comment due to limitation of space.

Comment: You need to read the Help section on how to use this site properly.  This is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threads.  What you have posted is not an answer, but clarifications to your problem, which should be added to your original question.